# How to update application version in control panel on auto_update using c++/QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have my QT application and I use MSi to install int on particuler system.
But on auto upgrade I am replacing application .exe.
On successful update I want to update application version in control panel without using MSI.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you have to edit the following Windows registry keys:

```
HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<your_app_name>" "DisplayVersion" "<new_version>"
```